# ASP.Net MVC 3 iTextSharp pdf table borders

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, itext

I have a page of my asp.net project to be output as pdf from html. Everything was fine except table borders. It seems like iTextSharp library only read table border="1" rather than table style="border-top:1px solid #333". I didn't manage to style the table to be display as I wish in the pdf page. Any idea how can I style it?